# QuickBooks provides a SDK, currently SDK14.0 with a dll, interop.QBFC14. I have not been able to find the file QBFC14lib?

Tags: c#, .net, qbfc

I found some code to register a dll and produce a typelib:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe /tlb /codebase Interop.QBFC14.dll, but it gives the following:

> RegAsm : error RA0000 : CLR assembly 'Interop.QBFC14.dll' was imported from a type library and cannot be re-exported to a type library.

I don't recall having to do anything to produce QBFC13Lib when I upgraded it a year or two ago.

> QuickBooks Desktop Pro 2020 Release R10P

> Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
> Version 16.8.4

An example of the error messages that comes with the missing 13 lib is:

> Cannot find the interop type that matches the embedded interop type 'QBFC13Lib.ENVisibleIfNot'. Are you missing an assembly reference?

The SDK13 version still works, but I need to get this done in due course.

Answer (score 0):

I started wondering more about that RegAsm error and decided to try substituting 'using Interop.QBFC14' for 'using QBFC13lib'. Much to my surprise, it seems to work. I have not yet tested extensively, but it compiles and opens a session with QuickBooks as it should.

Presumably somewhere in the QBSDK14.0 documentation there is an discussion of this name change, although I wasted a lot of time looking for that explanation.